# object of "refill": food or container?

Tags: verb-usage

I think "refill" as a verb only takes containers such as cups and bowls as objects. However, I am wondering whether it can take food as objects. Could we say "refill one's rice, beer, etc."?

Comment: Here'a an extract from a novel: “We've been looking for you.” “Here I am.” Again, she forced a smile she didn't really feel. She held up her empty mug. “Just heading to refill my beer.”

Comment: https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=FXmdBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT11&dq=%22heading+to+refill%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidnuHDsNrzAhWFxIsBHUPIBcAQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22heading%20to%20refill%22&f=false

Comment: As @Apollyon states, many restaurants advertise "Free refills for coffee". Of course, they *mean* to pour the coffee into a cup, but this colloquial usage is common and well-understood.

Comment: Not with food, you don't.

Comment: @FeliniusRex  But I've seen "refill your drink."